# Need to create XML based on another XML using XSLT2.0 based on distinct attributes and group by

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to generate a XML based on 2 other XMLs. I am polling a DB that returns details of people(There can be n number of people returned in query). **The final XML should have the exact number of *Data tags* as the *distinct name tags* in the XML coming from DB**. For Ex:

1st XML- Getting this from DB

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <name>John</name>
        <city>Boston</city>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>John</name>
        <city>Seattle</city>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>Allison</name>
        <city>Houston</city>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>John</name>
        <city>Boston</city>
    </child>
</parent>
```

2nd XML- Getting this from another source

```
<details>
    <detail>
        <city>Boston</city>
        <code>abc</code>
    </detail>
    <detail>
        <city>Houston</city>
        <code>xyz</code>
    </detail>
</details>
```

First I need to create 2 Data Tags as there are 2 distinct names(John and Allison) and then I need to check one by one if the **City** Tag for all **child** tags in the 1st XML matches the  in 2nd XML and then create **Details** Tag and copy **Code** Tag and its value in the Final XML.

1) If there are no matching entries, details tag should not be created, as there is no matching entry. 
2) No there wont be multiple matching entries ever. The data tag should be created based on the Distinct NAME tags and details tag based on the number of matching city tags.

Final XML to be generated

```
<FinalData>
    <Data>
        <name>John</name>
        <details>
            <city>Boston</city>
            <code>xyz</code>
        </details>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <name>Allison</name>
        <details>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <code>abc</code>
        </details>
    </Data>
</FinalData>
```

**EDIT 1:**

I am facing issues while populating the **code tag** as I have to match the **city tag** in both the XMLs and need a for loop for matching.

The below is my attempt -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="otherFile" select="document('SOF Input 2.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <FinalData>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="child" group-by="name">
                <data>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </name>
                    <details>
                        <city>
                            <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
                        </city>
                        <code>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$otherFile/details/detail">
                                <xsl:if test="parent/child/city='/city'">
                                    <!--I am getting stuck here - not able to get value here..i guess both city tags are referring to the same-->
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/code"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </code>
                    </details>
                </data>
                <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </FinalData>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting the below output with this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FinalData><data>
        <name>John</name>
        <details>
            <city>Boston</city>
            <code/>
        </details>
    </data>
<data>
        <name>Allison</name>
        <details>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <code/>
        </details>
    </data>
</FinalData>
```

Its slightly wrongly indented as well. Let me know if I missed anything.

**EDIT 2:**

I am afraid the scenario mentioned by Michael has come much earlier than expected. The **city** tag is going to repeat but come under a **parent** tag. The values of **city** tag will be unique within the **parent** tag. I have to take values from all the matching **city** tags,one by one, across all parents and populate in a manner where whatever matched in a **parent** tag goes in the respective **detail** tag in output XML. PFB the sample XMLs, that would explain in a better way -

1st XML -

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <name>John</name>
        <city>Boston</city>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>John</name>
        <city>Seattle</city>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>Allison</name>
        <city>Houston</city>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>John</name>
        <city>Boston</city>
    </child>
</parent>
```

2nd XML-

```
<details>
    <parent>
        <detail>
            <city>Boston</city>
            <code>abc</code>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <code>xyz</code>
        </detail>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <detail>
            <city>Boston</city>
            <code>abc</code>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <city>Seattle</city>
            <code>mno</code>
        </detail>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <detail>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <code>xyz</code>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <city>Seattle</city>
            <code>mno</code>
        </detail>
    </parent>
</details>
```

Final Expected XML-

```
<FinalData>
    <Data>
        <name>John</name>
        <details>
            <detail>
                <city value="Boston">abc</city>
            </detail>
            <detail>
                <city value="Boston">abc</city>
                <city value="Seattle">mno</city>
            </detail>
            <detail>
                <city value="Seattle">mno</city>
            </detail>
        </details>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <name>Allison</name>
        <details>
            <detail>
                <city value="Houston">xyz</city>
            </detail>
            <detail>
                <city value="Houston">xyz</city>
            </detail>
        </details>
    </Data>
</FinalData>
```

Hope this is clear, as I am not a good at giving explanations.

Comment: So where is your XSLT code attempt using `group-by` to group the first input? What happens if there is no matching city or if there is more than one matching city in the second XML?

Comment: This is rather trivial, using `xsl:for-each-group` to create the `Data` elements and a `key` for the `details`. Post your attempt so we can see where exactly you're stuck with this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have pasted my attempt now. Not sure the current code will work just for this scenario or for what I intend for. :)
And the other issue is comparing the city tags in both XMLs and putting a for-each I need to check for all the city tags in 2nd XML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have posted the attempt now. 
As to your query - There will always be unique cities in the 2nd XML. Not sure if in future that happens but not as of now. :)

Comment: @michael.hor257k   Can you please help me out here?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with your new requirements.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks, have posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61501441/create-xml-based-on-2-xmls-and-looking-up-values-in-both-files-using-xslt2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="otherFile" select="document('SOF Input 2.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="detail-by-city" match="detail" use="city" />

<xsl:template match="/parent">
    <FinalData>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="child" group-by="name">
            <data>
                <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('detail-by-city', current-group()/city, $otherfile)">
                    <details>
                         <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                    </details>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </data>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </FinalData>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming a group can have more than one matching entry in the other document, and you want to create a separate `details` node for each of those.

Comment: I guess there is a small misunderstanding - The **details** tag will be there always because **city** tag will come as it is from 1st XML,  but **code** tag should come based on 2nd XML.

Also, I had another doubt, will the same work in a scenario where there is exactly 1 matching entry or lets say 0 matching entry in the 2nd XML?

Comment: Since the `city` element is the same in both, it doesn't matter from where it comes. You need to clarify what should happen if (1) there is no matching entry and (2) there are multiple matching entries. As stated, my answer will create a separate `details` element for each matching entry. So there will be no `details` element if there are no matching entries. If you want something else, edit your question and add more examples. Currently your expected result is ambiguous.

Comment: 1) If there are no matching entries, **details** tag should be created, in that, only **city** will be populated but no **code** as there is no matching entry.
2) No there wont be multiple matching entries ever.
The details tag should be created based on the **Distinct NAME** tags. Hope this clears it out.

Comment: No, I am afraid it's not clear at all. In your example, the city Seattle is totally omitted from the output. So, it would seem that if no matching entry, no city. And 'distinct' has nothing with this. What if John has both Boston and Houston? Do you want to put them both in the same `details` element, without having a wrapper for each city/code pair?

Comment: I agree with you. Got confused with the data(as I am doing this as part of a POC). It makes sense that the details tag should be created based on the number of matching cities and then code to be populated. Have edited the question as well. Thanks for the help mate. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a key

```
<xsl:key name="city" match="detail" use="city"/>
```

and then use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('city', city, $otherFile)/code"/>
```

inside of your `for-each-group` to output the matching code.