# Extract value from one XML while matching template in other XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I have 2 XMLs. I am trying to run XSLT on 1st XML and matching data in 2nd XML using keys. While doing **template-match** on 2nd XML,I am unable to pull data from 1st XML's matching node(dont know how to pull any data from there per say) and populate it in there. Below are samples and expected output.

1st XML-

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <name>John</name>
        <city>Boston</city>
        <shortCityCode>B</shortCityCode>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>John</name>
        <city>Seattle</city>
        <shortCityCode>S</shortCityCode>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>Allison</name>
        <city>Houston</city>
        <shortCityCode>H</shortCityCode>
    </child>
</parent>
```

2nd XML - inline in the XSLT as variable

XSLT Attempt-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="details">
<details>
    <parent>
        <detail>
            <city>Boston</city>
            <code>abc</code>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <code>xyz</code>
        </detail>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <detail>
            <city>Boston</city>
            <code>abc</code>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <city>Seattle</city>
            <code>mno</code>
        </detail>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <detail>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <code>xyz</code>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <city>Seattle</city>
            <code>mno</code>
        </detail>
    </parent>
</details>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="parent-ref" match="parent" use="detail/city"/>
  <xsl:key name="detail-ref" match="parent/detail" use="city"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <FinalData>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="child" group-by="name">
            <Data>
                <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
            </Data>
            <Details>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent-ref', current-group()/city, $details)"/>
            </Details>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </FinalData>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="details/parent">
      <detail>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('detail-ref', current-group()/city, .)"/>
      </detail>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="detail">
      <city value="{shortCityCode}"> //Here I want to populate the value from 1st XML
          <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
      </city>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to extract the **shortCityCode** field and populate in 2nd Template call in the above XSLT. Below is the Snippet of above XSLT where its needed -

```
  <xsl:template match="detail">
      <city value="{shortCityCode}"> //shortCityCode from 1st XML where key is matching the values.
          <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
      </city>
  </xsl:template>
```

Expected Output -

```
<FinalData>
    <Data>
        <name>John</name>
        <details>
            <detail>
                <city value="B">abc</city>
            </detail>
            <detail>
                <city value="B">abc</city>
                <city value="S">mno</city>
            </detail>
            <detail>
                <city value="S">mno</city>
            </detail>
        </details>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <name>Allison</name>
        <details>
            <detail>
                <city value="H">xyz</city>
            </detail>
            <detail>
                <city value="H">xyz</city>
            </detail>
        </details>
    </Data>
</FinalData>
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Reducing the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem wold also be helpful.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the ques with my sample data which is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the template to

```
  <xsl:template match="detail">
      <city value="{current-group()[city = current()/city]/shortCityCode}">
          <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
      </city>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyY/5

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for this. Just wanted to understand how its referred here after the template was matched for the other XML?

Comment: In normal XSLT 2/3 the `current-group()` value is retained even outside of the `for-each-group` and if you process other nodes (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-current-group "Otherwise the invocation construct leaves the current group unchanged. In this situation the scope of the current group is effectively dynamic: it can be referenced within called templates and attribute sets") so the suggestion above simply exploits that you used grouping earlier and this group remains alive. The rest is an XPath predicate `[city = current()/city]` to compare the city of the context to the group.